# Numpy: applying a boolean mask to take average within original 3D matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 3D Numpy matrix `A` that looks as follows:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([ [ [90,  84,  88], [10, 30, 17], [7,  0,  4] ], 
               [ [88,  83, 102], [12, 14, 15], [12, 17, 7] ], 
               [ [150, 90, 103], [9, 16, 21],  [17, 7, 12] ] ])
A
array([[[ 90,  84,  88],
        [ 10,  30,  17],
        [  7,   0,   4]],

       [[ 88,  83, 102],
        [ 12,  14,  15],
        [ 12,  17,   7]],

       [[150,  90, 103],
        [  9,  16,  21],
        [ 17,   7,  12]]])
```

I subtract the elements of the matrix `A` along `axis 0` to create an identity matrix `B`:

```
B = A.T[..., None, :] - A.T[...,None]
B

array([[[[  0,  -2,  60],
     [  2,   0,  62],
     [-60, -62,   0]],

    [[  0,   2,  -1],
     [ -2,   0,  -3],
     [  1,   3,   0]],

    [[  0,   5,  10],
     [ -5,   0,   5],
     [-10,  -5,   0]]],


   [[[  0,  -1,   6],
     [  1,   0,   7],
     [ -6,  -7,   0]],

    [[  0, -16, -14],
     [ 16,   0,   2],
     [ 14,  -2,   0]],

    [[  0,  17,   7],
     [-17,   0, -10],
     [ -7,  10,   0]]],


   [[[  0,  14,  15],
     [-14,   0,   1],
     [-15,  -1,   0]],

    [[  0,  -2,   4],
     [  2,   0,   6],
     [ -4,  -6,   0]],

    [[  0,   3,   8],
     [ -3,   0,   5],
     [ -8,  -5,   0]]]])
```

I then remove the upper triangle of `B` and take the absolute values, saving this new matrix to `C`:

```
C = np.tril(B, k=0)
C = np.absolute(C)
C

array([[[[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 2,  0,  0],
         [60, 62,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 2,  0,  0],
         [ 1,  3,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 5,  0,  0],
         [10,  5,  0]]],


       [[[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 1,  0,  0],
         [ 6,  7,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [16,  0,  0],
         [14,  2,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [17,  0,  0],
         [ 7, 10,  0]]],


       [[[ 0,  0,  0],
         [14,  0,  0],
         [15,  1,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 2,  0,  0],
         [ 4,  6,  0]],

        [[ 0,  0,  0],
         [ 3,  0,  0],
         [ 8,  5,  0]]]])
```

My goal is to average the `A` along `axis 0` using `np.mean(A, axis=0)`, **but only if what's returned in `C` is within a certain threshold called `limit`**.

I've built a little mask, as follows:

```
limit = 8
E = np.where(C <= limit, True, False)
E

array([[[[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [False, False,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True]]],


       [[[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True],
         [ True, False,  True]]],


       [[[ True,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True],
         [False,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True]],

        [[ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True],
         [ True,  True,  True]]]])
```

But, how do I take averages of `A` along `axis 0` based only on the `True` values in `E`?

Any `False` values do not factor into the average.  The only values used as those associated with `True`.

If there is a more straightforward way of doing this, I'm all ears.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `E` has an extra dimension compared to `A`. How is it applied as a mask? It'd really help to explain the problem, too - there might be a more straightforward way to do this

Comment: Other than that, with a proper mask it is as easy as `(A * mask).sum(axis=0) / mask.sum(axis=0)`

Comment: The goal is to take the average of `A` along `axis 0`, but only if the elements of that identity matrix are within a certain tolerance.

Comment: @Marat -- using `mask = C <= limit`, then `(A * mask).sum(axis=0) / mask.sum(axis=0)` seems to return the original values of `A` - not the AVERAGES based on the True values in the mask (which is what I'm after).

Comment: `C <= limit` doesn't have the same dimensions, and cannot serve as a proper mask. It is a logical error, even though numpy seemingly figures out how to stretch/tile the array to make sense out of it

Comment: We know that we need a mask.  How does one apply such a mask properly?  Or, go from something that looks like `E` back to `A` (which is the goal)?  Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246289/discussion-between-equanimity-and-marat).